# Abstract class's inherited class not throwing fatal errors; undefined function calls fatal errors bizarely do

Tags: php, oop, abstract-class

Am I missing some error reporting mode so that this code:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

abstract class weapon
 {abstract function fire();}

class sword extends weapon
 {}

echo 'hello world';

?>
```

would actually report something telling me that the abstract method `fire()` was not defined in inheriting class?

it presently fails silently not echoing `hello world`

using php 5.4.24, php.ini have display_errors 0

---

running it on php 5.3.27, php.ini with display_errors 1, will throw this error:

> Fatal error: Class sword contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (weapon::fire) in /public_html/test.php on line 10

**there's something funny though**

because some fatal error *will* throw up, like undefined functions:

```
<?php

ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);

abstract class weapon
 {abstract function fire();}

class sword extends weapon
 {function fire()
      {}}

handle();

echo 'hello world';

?>
```

this code **will** throw `Fatal error: Call to undefined function handle() in /test.php on line 13` even though php.ini's `display_errors` *is* set to 0...

Comment: Sidenote: Your code did in fact throw this error `Fatal error: Class sword contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (weapon::fire)` - You're saying it didn't throw an error? - *"would actually report something telling me that the abstract method fire() was not defined in inheriting class?"*

Comment: yes, I'm running this exact code on a single script and it does not return any error

Comment: That is most bizarre. Edit: I was just going to mention what's been posted as an answer below, about `php.ini`'s default settings.

Comment: This would've worked `abstract class weapon { function fire(){ } }` and would've echo'd `hello world` if that's what your goal was to make it work. Or was that the intention, to throw an error on purpose?

Comment: I was checking that my script reported errors for further development and found it strange that a class could actually extend an abstract one without the required member function. Would have been a bad omen for later debugging now wouldn't it?

Comment: I couldn't elaborate on that. Classes are bit "abstract" for me; pardon the pun ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not seeing the error because your *php.ini* file has `display_errors` set to 0. Normally, using `ini_set('display_errors',1)` will work, [*except* in the case of a fatal error](http://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors):

> Although display_errors may be set at runtime (with ini_set()), it won't have any effect if the script has fatal errors. This is because the desired runtime action does not get executed.

Your script does indeed throw the following error:

> Fatal error: Class sword contains 1 abstract method and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (weapon::fire)

I recommend you enable `display_errors` in your development environment so you can ALWAYS see errors.

Comment: hmmm... this seems unlikely finally... how come this kind of fatal error error: `Fatal error: Call to undefined function handle() in test.php on line 37` will throw up?